# Sprite jitters when camera is smoothed

Tags: 2d, godot, godot4

Whenever I move my 2D Camera around (when smoothing is enabled), the sprites seem to shake, which is visually distracting - is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

## Godot 4

Enabling these two options should help you:

- Snap 2D Transforms to Pixel
- Snap 2D Vertices to Pixel

These options are under Project Settings, with "Advanced Settings" enabled in Rendering / 2D.

Godot 4 removed the old GPU Pixel Snap and replaced it with this to break it down into more specific GPU-agonistic options.

[image: The two options of Snap 2D Transforms displayed under the Snap category]